# How to unbootable pendrive

Tags: format

I created pendrive bootable through Startup Disk Creator. Now m trying to remove os from pendrive and trying to delete all data from pendrive but its not working. Even after formating, pendrive showing data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with SDC is that it is creating a ISO9660 partition that some OS's have trouble seeing.

Mkusb can rebuild a pendrive like new.
The wipe function can reset the drive to a msdos partition table with a FAT32 partition or GUID partition table with NTFS partition.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe